# Change Date Format(DD/MM/YYYY) in SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The Original SQL Statement is:

```
SELECT SA.[RequestStartDate] as 'Service Start Date', 
       SA.[RequestEndDate] as 'Service End Date', 
FROM
(......)SA
WHERE......
```

The output date format  is YYYY/MM/DD, but I want the output date format is DD/MM/YYYY. How can I modify in this statement?

Comment: If the datatype is `date(time)`, the format shown is dependant on your local settings. `Dates` don't have an inherent format. If you want to display a particular format, you'll have to `convert` it to a `varchar`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger After date(time) changed to varchar and then?

Comment: Check the configuration of the SQL client you are using. The _display_ format is applied by the application _displaying_ the values

Comment: Please edit the question and indicate what data type the dates are, i.e. date, datetime, varchar etc.

Answer (score 28):

Try like this...

```
select CONVERT (varchar(10), getdate(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

For more info : http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Changed to:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SA.[RequestStartDate],'dd/MM/yyyy') as 'Service Start Date', SA.[RequestEndDate] as 'Service End Date', FROM (......)SA WHERE......
```

Have no idea which SQL engine you are using, for other SQL engine, CONVERT can be used in SELECT statement to change the format in the form you needed.

Answer (score 5):

There's also another way to do this-

```
select TO_CHAR(SA.[RequestStartDate] , 'DD/MM/YYYY') as RequestStartDate from ... ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(10), SA.[RequestStartDate], 103) as 'Service Start Date', 
       convert(nvarchar(10), SA.[RequestEndDate], 103) as 'Service End Date', 
FROM
(......)SA
WHERE......
```

Or:

```
SELECT format(SA.[RequestStartDate], 'dd/MM/yyyy') as 'Service Start Date', 
       format(SA.[RequestEndDate], 'dd/MM/yyyy') as 'Service End Date', 
FROM
(......)SA
WHERE......
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a CONVERT() statement.

Try the following;

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SA.[RequestStartDate], 103) as 'Service Start Date', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SA.[RequestEndDate], 103) as 'Service End Date', FROM (......) SA WHERE.....
```

See [MSDN Cast and Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

I was using oracle and I had to select multiple columns and output the date column in YYYY-MM-DD format, and this worked
`select <column_1>, to_char(<date_column>, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as <Alias_name> from <table_name>`

Comment: OP is using SQL Server (T-SQL).

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT column1, DATE_FORMAT(ColumnName, "%d/%M/%Y") as column2, column3 FROM tableName;`

you can see here

w3: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34425455)