# Date format query in CASE expression

Tags: sql-server-2012, case, date-formatting

I am trying to output a date format within the below SQL

```
CASE
WHEN E.A_EXTTRNDTETME IS NOT NULL then LEFT(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 4)
    +SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 5, 2)+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 7, 2)
    +'-'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 9, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 11, 2)
    +':'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 13,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 15,3)
WHEN E.A_EXTTRNDTETME IS NULL then 
(
  SELECT TOP 1 A_EXTTRNDTETME FROM T_ATH_EXE 
  WHERE A_PAREXEID = E.A_EXEID ORDER BY A_ADDDTETME
)
ELSE ' text'
END as [TransactTime],
```

The second WHEN statement is returning 20180322141422883 but I would like this to be in the following format, like the values from the first branch:

```
20180322-14:14:22.883
```

But don't know how to do it inside the SELECT statement, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Date Format(DD/MM/YYYY) in SQL SELECT Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521322/change-date-formatdd-mm-yyyy-in-sql-select-statement)

Comment: @Stefan I don't really agree, the main problem here is logic / order of evaluation, not the simple formatting piece.

Comment: @Aaron  Hi, is there anyway that I can include the formatting in the same way that I have done in the line above.  There is a lot more to this query and this is merely a small part of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your entire query into a subquery, so you only have to apply formatting once. You can also use `COALESCE`, which is just a shorter way to write `CASE WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN this ELSE that END`. Finally, there are built in style options for formatting datetime values that avoid all that messy string manipulation (you can see [all the options here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)).

```
SELECT *, TransactTime = COALESCE
    (
      CONVERT(char(8), dt, 112) + '-' + CONVERT(char(12), dt, 108),
     ' text'
    )
FROM -- your larger query here
(
  SELECT 
    dt = COALESCE
    (
      E.A_EXTTDNDTETME, 
      (
        SELECT TOP (1) A_EXTTRNDTETME 
          FROM T_ATH_EXE 
          WHERE A_PAREXEID = E.A_EXEID 
          ORDER BY A_ADDDTETME
      )
    ), -- other columns... 
  FROM -- table...
) AS sub;
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by using the following:-

CASE
    WHEN E.A_EXTTRNDTETME IS NULL then (SELECT top 1 LEFT(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 4)+SUBSTRING(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 5, 2)+SUBSTRING(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 7, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 9, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 11, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 13,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(A_EXTTRNDTETME, 15,3) FROM T_ATH_EXE  WHERE A_PAREXEID = E.A_EXEID ORDER BY E.A_ADDDTETME)
    WHEN E.A_EXTTRNDTETME IS NOT NULL then LEFT(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 4)+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 5, 2)+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 7, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 9, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 11, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 13,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(E.A_EXTTRNDTETME, 15,3)
    ELSE ' text'
END as [TransactTime],